# Retrieving JSON data from realtime database (firebase) showing nothing

Tags: javascript, html, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have web app which uses json data but i want to use firebase realtime database, have implemented but shows nothing:

```
    var response = await fetch("laurel.json");
    var arr = await response.json();
    var laurel= arr[1];

            var dflt = {
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
           //   donut: true,
              gaugeWidthScale: 1.1,
              counter: true,
              hideInnerShadow: true
            }

            var ee1 = new r({
              id: 'ee1',
              value: laurel['Jennifer'],
              title: 'Jennifer ',
              defaults: dflt
            });

            var ee2 = new r({
              id: 'ee2',
              value: laurel['Peter'],
              title: 'Peter',
              defaults: dflt
            });

                var ee3 = new r({
              id: 'ee3',
              value: laurel['Justin'],
              title: 'Justin',
              defaults: dflt
            });

                var ee4 = new r({
              id: 'ee4',
              value: laurel['Alex'],
              title: 'Alex',
              defaults: dflt
            });

          });
```

I have changed that fetching like this :

```
var response = await fetch("https://**********.firebaseio.com/person.json);
```

and i have also put my json data in realtime database and rules :

```
{
    "rules": {
    "laurel": {
           ".read": true
        }
    }
}
```

still shows nothing ... any idea ?

Comment: Could you upload your complete codes?

Comment: @Pyae Phyoe Shein  There is just json in realtime database : [{
        "Jennifer": 45,
        "Peter": 89,
        "Justin": 35,
        "Alex": 25
    },
    {
        "Jennifer": 75,
        "Peter": 59,
        "Justin": 85,
        "Alex": 95
    },
    {
        "Jennifer": 55,
        "Peter": 15,
        "Justin": 45,
        "Alex": 67
    }
]

Comment: @Pyae Phyoe Shein  it is working fine without realtime database, but my point is using realtime database

Comment: anybody here have any idea ?

Comment: What does `showing nothing` exactly mean? Is `arr` empty or does the `fetch` or any other part of that code fail due to an error? (I don't see any error handling in your code)

Comment: @t.niese i think the problem is with fetching, is it correctly written ? i get this error : var valuesparsed = arr[0]; (Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null) but when  puting json outside realtime database on its onw url then it doesnt show this error so it means problem is with fetching ?

Comment: Then you should check what the request to `person.json` returns by looking into the network tab of the developer tools.

Comment: @t.niese its written: person.json status : 200, Type: fetch,  Initiator: person1.html:70, size: 314 b, Time: 169 ms. response, preview are 'null'

Comment: It was about the content the response returned, if it contains data or not and what kind of data. Anyhow the error says `var valuesparsed = arr[0]; ` but the code is `var personparsed = arr[1];` so the error and the shown code are not related.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185686/discussion-between-walee-and-t-niese).

Comment: @t.niese  In my version i have just changed 'person' into 'values' just different name but error is same

Comment: In order to be able to answer questions well in the context of a platform like SO, it is essential that the person asking the questions is exact. Everything else is misleading and guides the one trying to help into the wrong direct. So always show the error messages that belongs to the posted code.

Comment: And what is the content of the request to `person.json` and its content type?

Comment: @t.niese ok thanks, this is content :  [{ "Jennifer": 45, "Peter": 89, "Justin": 35, "Alex": 25 }, { "Jennifer": 75, "Peter": 59, "Justin": 85, "Alex": 95 }, { "Jennifer": 55, "Peter": 15, "Justin": 45, "Alex": 67 } ]

Comment: I've found solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution.

There should be a node after project folder. If your project is called `my-project`, your realtime json structure will be like

[image]

after that, you could browse your firebase realtime data as follow, https://hn-firebase-47370.firebaseio.com/person.json.

The main problem is you forgot/missed to add sub-level node for your data structure.

Example is here: https://repl.it/@PyaePhyoe/TiredNervousMouse

Comment: could you possibly implement sub-level node in my code, coudnt make it work, just wanna know if problem is there

Comment: You don't need to do anything in your code, problem is your firebase realtime database form. Is that you added manually or by dynamically?

Comment: i imported json data

Comment: @walee here you go: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=itgTPTC2bEY and don't forgot to mark as correct answer and upvote. :)